# How were the probabilities calculated

Tags: probability, markov-process, garch

I'm trying to calculate the probabilities in the paper [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uF8hK.jpg) but I'm getting different results. In the paper, the forecasted smoothed probabilities are calculated as follows:

$$\mathbb{P}(S_{t+1} = i|\mathcal{F}_T) = p_{1i} \mathbb{P}(S_{t} = 1|\mathcal{F}_T) + p_{2i} \mathbb{P}(S_{t} = 2|\mathcal{F}_T) + ... + p_{ji}\mathbb{P}(S_{t} = i|\mathcal{F}_T),$$

where $p_{ji}$ shows the elements of the transition matrix $\mathbf{P}$.

The transition matrix is:

$$\mathbf{P} = \begin{bmatrix}
0.98252298 & 0.01747702 \\
0.16218110 & 0.83781890 
\end{bmatrix}$$

Using the first formula, to calculate the smoothed probability at November 2018 we get:

$$\mathbb{P}(S_{t+1} = 2|\mathcal{F}_T) = p_{12} \mathbb{P}(S_{t} = 1|\mathcal{F}_T) + p_{22} \mathbb{P}(S_{t} = 2|\mathcal{F}_T) = 0.16218110 × 0.003247 + 0.83781890 × (1 - 0.003247) = 8356251041,$$

Which is way different than the probability predicted 0.019831 in table 2.

**Edit:**

The paper can be freely downloaded as shown in the image below.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uF8hK.jpg) https://aip.scitation.org/doi/abs/10.1063/1.5141654

[image]

Comment: The paper is behind a paywall, so unless you provide a full account of the context, we do not have the information needed to know we are fully and correctly understanding your question.

Comment: Dear @whuber, the paper can be freely downloaded. The formula for calculating the forecasted smoothed probabilities is in page 2. As for the transition matrix it's in page 5 and the forecasted probabilities are in page 6. If there is any detail that I need to add I will gladly do it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Dear @whuber, was the article accessible to you?